# Using props.type with react styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

hope you are keeping well. I'm stuck as to how to use the following props in my component.

```
const Container = styled.div`
    background-color: ${props =>
      ({
        primary: 'blue',
        danger: 'red',
        warning: 'yellow'
      })[props.type]
    }
`
```

and then in my app, I'm trying to do the following

```
...
<Container primary />
...
```

But there is no background-color change. I'm doing something stupid. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing props to the Styled component works exactly like in React. What you are doing is passing a prop named `primary` which has a type `boolean`.

In your Container, you are checking for `type` prop which is not there, so all you need to do pass a `type` prop with either one of this value `primary | danger | warning`

Code :

```js
<Container type="primary" />
```

Comment: Ofcourse! Thank you. I was thrown simply because of the use of the word 'type' in the prop. I started thinking that I had not seen this pattern before, whereas if the code was 'prop.color' or 'prop.uiState' or something I hope I would have understood.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const Container = styled.div`
  /* Background color with inline if/else. 'white' color is a fallbak  */
  background: ${props => props.primary ? "blue" : props.danger ? "red" : props.warning ? "yellow" : "white"  };
  /* You can do the same with other properties */
  color: ${props => props.primary ? "white" : "#222"};
  
  /* More properties will be applied to all */
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
`;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container danger>Hello World!</Container>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/styled-components/4.3.2/styled-components.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

See more examples at styled-components [Docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props)

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution to what you trying to achieve it using some other property than `boolean`:

```
// type = 'primary' / 'danger' / 'warning'
<Container type={type} />;

const TYPE = {
  primary: 'blue',
  danger: 'red',
  warning: 'yellow'
};

const Container = styled.div`
  background-color: ${({ type }) => TYPE[type]};
`;
```

As for your current code, you can try:

```
// Only `blue` or `red`
const Container = styled.div`
  background-color: ${({ primary }) => (primary ? 'blue' : 'red')};
`;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time Dennis. I am trying to write a ‘not-so-simple’ condition where there are more than two options as in your Conditional (ternary) operator